# Heroku Request blocked

Tags: heroku, http-status-code-400

in my application (deployed in Heroku), there is a request (GET) that is blocked in the infrastructure layer, the request does not get to execute the code of my application. It returns an error status=400 and connect=0ms and does not carry any associated Heroku error code and description. The request never reaches the application.

It only happens with this GET request, when it comes from the production server. if I make the request from postman it is received correctly with status=200

The other requests have not problem and are executed correctly from the production server.

This is an example:

```
2021-08-20T10: 27: 02.217551 + 00: 00 heroku [router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/get" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2920634e-87f2-4b2c-be60-b38497c53e58  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=47 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was identified and corrected.

The problem was that one of the headers of the GET request was being sent to null and the request was rejected as Bad Request Exception before entering the APP.

regards

Comment: im having the same problem could you elaborate on your answer by providing some code?